# Design for Bit manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am creating a plugin. I have a set of different types of values for a record. So, lets say, for each record I have following data

- type : value
- A : a1
- B : b1
- C : c1
- D : d1

Now, for each record, I want to keep an applied array -

- type : applied
- A : true
- B : false
- C : true
- D : true

Now, I take && of all values of A, B, C, D in applied array, and based on true/false of final AND, I decide if the record is valid or not.

Now, I do not want to keep and array for such a thing. I want to keep 4 bits with 0/1 value and take '&' using bitwise operations which will be faster. I want to know how I can implement such a thing? What will **n** bit variable look like.

I am creating a plugin, so I will not know in advance if there will be 4 such types. There can be any 'n' such types (n < 32), so that I will have to keep n such bits.

**This is what thought so far**

1. I will keep and integer variable with value = 0. (all bits will be 0
   initially) I dont know how to keep and integer with 32 bits / n bits.
2. I will keep a count of how many n types I have
3. To set to true, somehow I will have to go and set i-th bit to 1, or
   to 0 if I have to set it to false. I dont know how to do that.
4. To find AND, I will find the first bit which is equal to 0 in those
   n bits. If there is a 0, my final value is 0, else its 1.

Language - javascript/jquery

Any example with function signatures only will be helpful

Comment: You may want to have a look at [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) in javascript. IDK if this is a proper source, haven't worked that much with javascript so far.

Comment: Thanks @Paul for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will keep and integer variable with value = 0. (all bits will be 0 initially) I dont know how to keep and integer with 32 bits / n bits.

JavaScript doesn't have an integer type, but the `Number` type is guaranteed to be able to represent any integer from −2³¹ to 2³¹−1. You can use [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) on `Number`'s as if they were 32-bit signed integers.

> To set to true, somehow I will have to go and set i-th bit to 1, or to 0 if I have to set it to false. I dont know how to do that.

In order to set `i`-th bit of `x` to 1 do this:

```
x |= (1 << i)
```

In order to set `i`-th bit of `x` to 0 do this:

```
x &= ~(1 << i)
```

> To find AND, I will find the first bit which is equal to 0 in those n bits. If there is a 0, my final value is 0, else its 1.

There is a simpler way to check if an integer `x` equals to `n` ones in binary.

```
var isAllOnes = x === (1 << n) - 1;
```

Example for `n == 8`:

`(1 << n)` is 256, or `100000000` in binary (one and 8 zeroes).

`(1 << n) - 1` is 255, or `11111111` in binary (8 ones).

Comment: This is quite helpful. I will try to implement it.  Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. I did not know that I can use Numbers (integers) to perform bitwise operations. (lame me)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has the usual `<<` operator for left-shifting, so `1 << n` will get you a number with the n'th bit set. (This won't work correctly for large `n`, but `n` in the range `0` to `31` inclusive should be fine, which you claim in your question is large enough for you.)

You can use the bitwise or operator `|` to set a bit with this; e.g. `x | 1 << n` will be just like `x` but with the `n`th bit set. Similarly `~` and `&` can be used to turn off a bit: `x & ~(1 << n)` will be just like `x` but with the `n`th bit cleared.

Testing that all the bits are set is fairly easy, too: `x === (1 << n)-1` will check whether all the bits from `0` to `n-1` are set.

Comment: Not an expert in javascript, but AFAIK javascript supports bit-shifting. So why waste your time with `pow`? Seems quite inefficient and not exactly descriptive to me.

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I'm also not an expert, and answered having basically done a few seconds of Googling, and the first resource I found on the names of bitwise operations didn't mention bit shifting. You're right that bit-shifting is supported, though, and I'll update my answer accordingly.